# How can I get the unique items in a bash array?

Tags: bash

If I have this array

```
arra[0]='Debian'
arra[1]='Debian'
arra[2]='Ubuntu'
arra[3]='Suse'
```

How can I stock in a new array Debian, Ubuntu and Suse only ? like this

```
new[0]='Debian'
new[1]='Ubuntu'
new[2]='Suse'
```

Comment: Have a look at this over on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

A working answer:

```
eval newArray=($(for i in  "${arra[@]}" ; do  echo "\"$i\"" ; done | sort -u))
```

It works with spaces in your array elements like in `'Red Hat'`: you need to print quote `""` around your variable value *`("\"$i\"")`* and `eval` the result.

A more elegant alternative

```
eval newArray=($(printf "%q\n" "${arra[@]}" | sort -u))
```

where the format `%q` is needed to quote the output of `printf`.

Comment: Thus works but **eval** in shell scripting is almost always a bad idea. Better to upgrade to bash 4 and get true associative arrays.